# How to re-load the model when Spark streaming process is running?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I have the configuration file `myConfig.conf` in which the path to the prediction model is defined as a parameter `pathToModel`. I am reading this file once in order to get `pathToModel`. 
However, now I want to slightly update the logic - I want to be able to re-load the prediction model any time `pathToModel` is updated in the configuration file.

This is my current code:

```
val pathToModelPar = ConfigFactory.load("myConfig.conf")
val pathToModel = pathToModelPar.getString("pathToModel")
val model = GradientBoostedTreesModel.load(sc,pathToModel)
myDStream.foreachRDD(myRDD => {
  myRDD.foreachPartition({ partitionOfRecords =>
    //...
    val predictions = model.predict(...)
    //...
  })
})
```

I was thinking that the file `config.conf` could be checked every hour and then the IF-THEN rule can be applied - if a new `pathToModel` is different from a current `pathToModel`, then `model` is re-loaded.

However, I do not know how to implement this re-loading in the context of streaming data. As far as I understand, if I put IF-THEN rule **outside** from `myDStream.foreachRDD(myRDD => {...})`, then it will be checked only at the start of the streaming process. If I put IF-THEN rule **inside** `myDStream.foreachRDD(myRDD => {...})`, then I will get Task serialization error due to using `sc` in `load`. That's the problem. Any idea?

I tried this approach, but it loads the model only once:

```
var pathToModelPar = ConfigFactory.load("myConfig.conf")
var pathToModel = pathToModelPar.getString("pathToModel")
var model = GradientBoostedTreesModel.load(sc,pathToModel)

val ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)
val task = new Runnable {
    def run() = {
      pathToModelPar = ConfigFactory.load("myConfig.conf")
      pathToModel = pathToModelPar.getString("pathToModel")
      model = GradientBoostedTreesModel.load(sc,pathToModel)
    }
  }
val f = ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)

myDStream.foreachRDD(myRDD => {
  myRDD.foreachPartition({ partitionOfRecords =>
    //...
    val predictions = model.predict(...)
    //...
  })
})
```